# Powershell command for waiting one process to get completed

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-1.0

I have power shell script which will perform multiple tasks like uninstalling,removing and again installing wsp solutions.I am facing an issue like the first process is taking too long time for uninstalling solution so that other process has to wait till the first action has to get completed fully.Now i am giving sleep time but it has some problem while different machines speed gets varies.. I also aware about calling notepad like an external function but i dont want that has to happen here.Apart from that any solutions are availabe like I need to wait for first process to get complete before starting the second process.

```
$InstallDIR = "F:\new\source\UpdatedWSPFiles"
$Dir = get-childitem $InstallDIR -Recurse
$WSPList = $Dir | where {$_.Name -like "*.wsp*"}
Foreach ($wsp in $WSPList )
{
$WSPFullFileName = $wsp.FullName
$WSPFileName = $wsp.Name
try
{
Write-Host -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue "Working on $WSPFileName"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Retracting Solution"
Uninstall-SPSolution -AllWebApplications -Identity "$WSPFileName" -Confirm:$false 
sleep 100

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Removing Solution from farm"
Remove-SPSolution -Identity "$WSPFileName" -Confirm:$false -Force
sleep 60

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Adding solution to farm"
Add-SPSolution "$WSPFullFileName"  -Confirm:$false 
sleep 60
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Do you want the foreach loop to run in parallell? (All solutions gets uninstalled at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

you can try start-process with the -wait switch :

```
    PS> $p="C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
    PS> $params="-command &{ if ((Get-PSSnapin `"Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell`" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin `"Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell`"
}
Uninstall-SPSolution -AllWebApplications -Identity `"$WSPFileName`" -Confirm:$false}"
    PS> Start-Process $p $params -Wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you could try

```
Start-Job -Name "jobname" -ScriptBlock { Uninstall-SPSolution -AllWebApplications -Identity "$WSPFileName" -Confirm:$false }
```

and

```
Wait-Job -Name "jobname" -Timeout "maximum wait time"
```

Comment: Thanks for all replays.Actually I am looking for a foreach command which will check every 10 sec whether the uninstalling process got completed or not and if it got completed then it will come out of the loop and continue with oter process.Untill and unless first process gets complete, foreach has to keep on check.

Comment: Sorry, guess I missed something :(